# Can't upgrade NVidia packages

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, nvidia, apt

I want to upgrade my Ubuntu from 19.04 to 20.04, but it's not possible until I update all my packages.

```sh
❯ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife

Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

So, I'm trying to update my packages:

```sh
❯ sudo apt update
Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-10-0-local-10.0.130-410.48  InRelease
Ign:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-10-0-local-10.0.130-410.48  InRelease
Get:2 file:/var/cuda-repo-10-0-local-10.0.130-410.48  Release [574 B]
Get:2 file:/var/cuda-repo-10-0-local-10.0.130-410.48  Release [574 B]
Hit:3 http://repo.yandex.ru/yandex-disk/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                           
Hit:5 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                                 
Hit:6 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease                                                                                                                            
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gophers/archive/ubuntu disco InRelease                                                                                                                  
Hit:8 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease                                                                                                                    
Hit:9 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                           
Hit:10 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease                                                                                                                                  
Hit:11 https://storage.googleapis.com/bazel-apt stable InRelease                                                                                                                       
Hit:12 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports InRelease                                                                                                                 
Hit:13 https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu vs-bionic InRelease                                                                                                               
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu disco InRelease                                                                                                   
Hit:15 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease                                                                                                                  
Ign:16 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64  InRelease                                                                                            
Hit:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu disco InRelease                                                                                                               
Hit:18 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server-2019 xenial InRelease                                
Ign:19 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu disco InRelease                                                               
Hit:20 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server-2017 xenial InRelease          
Hit:21 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu disco Release                                           
Ign:22 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64  InRelease
Hit:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/apps/ubuntu disco InRelease
Hit:24 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/19.04/prod disco InRelease                        
Hit:25 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64  Release      
Hit:26 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64  Release
Hit:27 http://ppa.launchpad.net/longsleep/golang-backports/ubuntu disco InRelease
Hit:28 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lyzardking/ubuntu-make/ubuntu disco InRelease
Hit:29 http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu disco InRelease
Hit:30 http://ppa.launchpad.net/peek-developers/stable/ubuntu disco InRelease
Hit:31 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu disco InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                      
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
4 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

It says that I can upgrade 4 of them. Let's see what they are.

```sh
❯ apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
cuda-drivers/unknown 450.36.06-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 418.87.01-1]
cuda/unknown 11.0.1-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 10.1.243-1]
libnvidia-common-450/unknown 450.36.06-0ubuntu1 all [upgradable from: 450.36.06-0ubuntu1]
libxnvctrl0/unknown 450.36.06-0ubuntu1 amd64 [upgradable from: 450.36.06-0ubuntu1]
```

Let's upgrade them.

```sh
❯ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  cuda-command-line-tools-11-0 cuda-compiler-11-0 cuda-cudart-11-0 cuda-cudart-dev-11-0 cuda-cuobjdump-11-0 cuda-cupti-11-0 cuda-cupti-dev-11-0 cuda-documentation-11-0
  cuda-driver-dev-11-0 cuda-gdb-11-0 cuda-libraries-11-0 cuda-libraries-dev-11-0 cuda-memcheck-11-0 cuda-nsight-11-0 cuda-nsight-compute-11-0 cuda-nsight-systems-11-0 cuda-nvcc-11-0
  cuda-nvdisasm-11-0 cuda-nvml-dev-11-0 cuda-nvprof-11-0 cuda-nvprune-11-0 cuda-nvrtc-11-0 cuda-nvrtc-dev-11-0 cuda-nvtx-11-0 cuda-nvvp-11-0 cuda-samples-11-0 cuda-sanitizer-11-0
  cuda-toolkit-11-0 cuda-tools-11-0 cuda-visual-tools-11-0 golang-1.13-go golang-1.13-src golang-src libcublas-11-0 libcublas-dev-11-0 libcufft-11-0 libcufft-dev-11-0 libcurand-11-0
  libcurand-dev-11-0 libcusolver-11-0 libcusolver-dev-11-0 libcusparse-11-0 libcusparse-dev-11-0 libnpp-11-0 libnpp-dev-11-0 libnvidia-common-450 libnvjpeg-11-0 libnvjpeg-dev-11-0
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages have been kept back:
  cuda cuda-drivers
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libnvidia-common-450 libxnvctrl0
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/31.4 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 354920 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libnvidia-common-450_450.36.06-0ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Checking for existing driver runfile install
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/preinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/preinst: [[: not found
Unpacking libnvidia-common-450 (450.36.06-0ubuntu1) over (450.36.06-0ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libxnvctrl0_450.36.06-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxnvctrl0:amd64 (450.36.06-0ubuntu1) over (450.36.06-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-common-450 (450.36.06-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libxnvctrl0:amd64 (450.36.06-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.29-0ubuntu2) ...
```

The problem is that they are not upgraded.

```sh
❯ apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
cuda-drivers/unknown 450.36.06-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 418.87.01-1]
cuda/unknown 11.0.1-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 10.1.243-1]
libnvidia-common-450/unknown 450.36.06-0ubuntu1 all [upgradable from: 450.36.06-0ubuntu1]
libxnvctrl0/unknown 450.36.06-0ubuntu1 amd64 [upgradable from: 450.36.06-0ubuntu1]
```

Do I do something wrong? It might be that I don't understand the real cause of why I can't move from Ubuntu 19.04 to Ubuntu 20.04. Any ideas?

Comment: ask on unix and linux community or if you use ubunut then post on ask ubuntu

Answer (score 9):

I just came across the same issue when trying to upgrade my `cuda` on Ubuntu 20.04.

`sudo apt upgrade` will only add upgrade/add packages, it will never remove packages.

However, upgrading cuda usually requires removing a bunch of old nvidia driver packages and replacing them with new packages.

`sudo apt full-upgrade` can remove packages if required to update packages:

> `full-upgrade` (apt-get(8))
>
> full-upgrade performs the function of upgrade but will remove currently installed packages if this is needed to upgrade the system as a whole.

(from `man apt` https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/apt.8.html)

Unfortunately, at least for apt version 2.0.5, `sudo apt full-upgrade` still didn't want to update `cuda`.

The [Debian buster upgrade notes](https://www.debian.org/releases/buster/amd64/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html#upgrading-full) suggests that when `apt full-upgrade` doesn't work, you should either manually run `install` on the affected packages: `sudo apt install cuda`, or use `aptitude`'s more powerful package resolution algorithms:

I can confirm that using either `sudo aptitude full-upgrade` or `sudo apt install cuda` works, see the following outputs (edited for brevity)

### Using apt install cuda

```
❯ sudo apt install cuda
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
 cuda-11-2 cuda-command-line-tools-11-2 ...
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  cuda-11-3 cuda-command-line-tools-11-3 ...
The following packages will be REMOVED
  cuda-drivers-460 libnvidia-cfg1-460 ...
The following NEW packages will be installed
  cuda-11-3 cuda-command-line-tools-11-3 ...
The following packages will be upgraded:
  cuda cuda-drivers
2 to upgrade, 68 to newly install, 16 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 2,248 MB of archives.
After this operation, 4,603 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

### Using aptitude full-upgrade

`aptitude` isn't installed by default, so you may need to run `sudo apt install aptitude` first to install it. Remember that although `full-upgrade` is usually safe, since it does remove packages, it can occasionally break things in your system.

```
❯ sudo aptitude full-upgrade
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  cuda-11-3{a} cuda-command-line-tools-11-3{a} ...
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  cuda-11-2{u} cuda-command-line-tools-11-2{u} ...
The following packages will be upgraded:
  cuda cuda-drivers ...
2 packages upgraded, 68 newly installed, 65 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 2,248 MB of archives. After unpacking 16.5 MB will be freed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libnvidia-compute-460 : Conflicts: libcuda-10.0-1 which is a virtual package, provided by: ...

 libnvidia-compute-465 : Conflicts: libcuda-10.0-1 which is a virtual package, provided by: ...

The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Remove the following packages:                            
1)     libnvidia-compute-460 [460.32.03-0ubuntu1 (<NULL>, now)]



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo apt install cuda cuda-drivers libnvidia-common-450 libxnvctrl0
```

If the same problem with upgrade another packages, you need to install them instead upgrade.